# Inheritance and Telerik RadControls (RadMenu)

Tags: c#, inheritance

I am trying to create a custom (CustTreeView) control by inheriting from a Telerik control (RadTreeView) by doing the following:

```
public class CustTreeView : RadTreeView
```

but not all methods appear to be inherited. For example, I can do:

```
  RadTreeView r = new RadTreeView();  
  r.LoadContentFile("Sample.xml");
```

but not:

```
 CustTreeView r = new CustTreeView ();
 r.LoadContentFile("Sample.xml");
```

so LoadContentFile doesn't appear to be in CustTreeView! Any explanation?

Here is the RadTreeView LoadContentFile method signature:

```
public void LoadContentFile(string path)
```

Comment: Can you please provide class details for the classes ?

Comment: Does the second code fails at compile or at run time?
If it fails at run time, I'll bet the LoadContentFile method is abstract and you will have to implement it (at least call base.LoadContentFile)

Comment: What is the compile error message?

Comment: Ask rashad from the telerik team. he is the best!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes it is intellisense refreshing issue. You can try to manually type it and build, it will compile and the intellisence will be back.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [docs](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet/treeview/radtreeview-telerik.webcontrols.radtreeview-loadcontentfile.html), that method is public. What error are you getting? Perhaps you're just missing a reference and Intellisense can't resolve the method for you?

Answer (score 1):

The method is public so it must remain available in the sub-class. Try re-building your solution for intellisense to update.